# mvc4 authorisation doesn't work with ASP.net Configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am following along this series:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/using-web-api-with-entity-framework,-part-1

It all goes well up to the point, where one is requiered to use the ASP.net Configuration tool to create a role Administrator, a user and then log in.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]
```

works fine, but I can't log in with the "Admin" account created via ASP.NET configuration; or, vice versa, see the users which I registered in the demo on the ASP.NET configuration panel.

And why did this demo create 2 Connectionstrings to two differend databases?

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebStore-20120820081613;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebStore-20120820081613.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="OrdersContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=OrdersContext-20120820083248; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|OrdersContext-20120820083248.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I'm running the whole thing on Windows Server 2008 R2; Visual Studio Express 12.

Comment: the OrdersContext connection string Is for entity framework because entity framework store alittle more information in connection string then normal connection string

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong please: "ASP.NET Configuration Panel" created users are stored via Default Connection; the AccountController uses OrdersContext to check if a user is registered/allowed to log in.

How is this supposed to work - or even better: where did I go wrong?

Comment: have you set the membership configuration in web.confg

Comment: No, I did not. I did follow the instructions in the link above bit by bit and did not alter anything on my own.

Comment: go to this http://forums.asp.net/t/1773914.aspx/1 and configure it

Comment: did that, IIS 8.0 throws an error. complains about:
`<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
`

Comment: I put the membership section into the <system.web> section.
Now the Account Controller is throwing an Error because the Roleprovider needs to be an instance ob ExtendedMembershipProvider.

Something is awefully wrong here, if this is supposed to be a quick n dirty demonstration of webAPI

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by recreating the application with visual studio 2010.
... copied the connectionstring to the vs2010 project and voilá ... done.